# Flutter Images in GridView scrolling lag

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get images from URL and then put them all in GridView and scroll them. In emulator, the scroll is extremely laggy and cpu usage is always 100% when scrolling. Should I be doing something with the images before putting it in the GridView?

The code is pretty simple, something like this.

```
final List<String> urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4];

GridView.builder(
  itemCount: urls.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Image.network(urls[index])
)
```

I also tried with CachedNetworkImage and the same thing happen. The image size is the typical image size that you get from iPhone camera.

Comment: That seems fine. It's probably the emulator performance, try with release mode (`flutter run --release`) and see if it gets better (it should), but I recommend you to try on a physical device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep in mind that the emulator will never give you the same experience as a physical device specially if you are running in debug mode, try to run in release mode (flutter run --release).

That said if you don't have a lot of images in the list you can try to pre-cache images like this at the beginning (initState maybe).

```
urls.forEach((url){
    precacheImage(NetworkImage(url),context);
});
```